# CSS list-style: lower-alpha issue

Tags: html-lists

Standard lower-alpha produces:
a.
b.
c.

I need something like this:
a)
b)
c)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/pPwbp/)

Added a bracket using `::before` and then fiddled with margins to force it to the right place

Comment: Very nice. I added "text-indext: -5px;" to the li, and everything lined up perfectly for multi-line items. Thank you for your help, Andy.